# Oracle Coherence - retrieving specific Member using Key

Tags: oracle-coherence

I have used Partitioned scheme and used data-affinity to store related data together on Cluster member.

I am only interested to execute my Invocable on a subset of entire data. Can I find specific members storing subset of data I am interested in?

Currently I do this: partitionedService.getOwnershipEnabledMembers() which gets me all nodes running this service in cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PartitionedService.getKeyOwner(Object key)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15357_01/coh.360/e15725/com/tangosol/net/PartitionedService.html#getKeyOwner_java_lang_Object_)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EntryProcessor and execute it against the data that you want to process, eg.

```
public class MyProc extends AbstractProcessor implements Serializable
  {
  public Object process(Entry entry)
    {
    System.out.println("*** processing " + entry.getKey());
    }
  }
```

Now to run that, just:

```
cache.invokeAll(collKeys, new MyProc());
```

... where "collKeys" is a collection of keys to your cache, or:

```
cache.invokeAll(filter, new MyProc());
```

... where "filter" is a query on your cache.